# Find a element of a list in a another list in Prolog

Tags: list, search, find, prolog

i try to solve a problem about lists but i can't... :(

**PLAYER(TEAM,[PLAYERS WHO PLAY IN THAT TEAM]).**

```
player(milan,[seedorf,zambrotta,gattuso]).
player(inter,[seedorf,ronaldo,zambrotta]).
player(realmadrid,[seedorf,zidane,ronaldo]).
```

and i try to write predicates that returns 2 Lists; P1 and P2...

```
find(P1,P2).
```

For example; if my goal is:

```
find([milan,inter],X). returns X:[seedorf,zambrotta]. 
                     players who played juventus and also inter 
find([inter,realmadrid],X). returns X:[seedorf,ronaldo]  
                    players who played inter and also realmadrid
find(X,[seedorf]). returns X:[juventus,inter,realmadrid]
                     teams that seedorf played
find(X,[seedorf,ronaldo]). returns X:[inter,realmadrid]
                     teams that seedorf and ronaldo played.
```

i try to solve this but i can't go further than that (and it is not even enough to try P2 list members find in player facts :( ) :  MOREOVER I CANNOT USE "!" because of lecture restrictions.

```
find(P1,[P2|P2s]):-findall(X,player(X,P2),P1),find(P1,P2s).
```

Thanks A Lot....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you accept both `P1` and `P2` as inputs, I suggest to break down both `P1` and `P2` by their structures to do recursion. One solution could be finding all team of a specific player and finding all players playing for a specific team:

```
find1([T], L) :- player(T, L).
find1([T|Ts], L) :- player(T, L0), find1(Ts, L1), intersection(L0, L1, L).

find2(L, [P]) :- findall(X, (player(X, Y), member(P, Y)), L).
find2(L, [P|Ps]) :- findall(X, (player(X, Y), member(P, Y)), L0), find2(L1, Ps), intersection(L0, L1, L).

find(X, Y) :- is_list(X), find1(X, Y).
find(X, Y) :- is_list(Y), find2(X, Y).
```

Hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: find([T], L) :- player(T, L), !. find([T|Ts], L2) :- player(T, L0), find(Ts, L1), intersection(L0, L1, L2). thanks a lot pad.. but i cannot run the this part.. when my goal i.e. find(milan,X) program failed like in a infinite loop.. by the way.. "!" is this a break code ?.. i am not allowed to use this... Is possible to write this without "!" ?

Comment: "!" is the cut predicate, it is used to avoid backtracking when a solution is already found. I have updated the code to remove "!", it should work by now.

Comment: Thanks a lot pad... 
Moreover,
How can i do that:   

    if my goal find(X,Y).

can it return like:

    X=[milan] , Y=[seedorf,zambrotta,gattuso]);  
    X=[milan,inter] , Y=[seedorf,zambrotta];
    X=[milan,inter,realmadrid] , Y=[seedorf];
    false.

i try to do it with:

    find(X,Y):-not(is_list(X)),not(is_list(Y))..... but i failed to continue..